# Trying to get class name from tr tag - 'undefined'

Tags: javascript, class, getelementbyid, tablerow

I need to get the class name from a given `<tr>` tag, but am unable to do so.

```
<table cellpadding=5 cellspacing=5>
    <tr id='cat_abc123' class='class_a'>
        <td>foo</td>
        <td><input type='checkbox' name='cb1' value='1' onClick="info(this, 'abc123')">
    </tr>
</table>

 <script language='javascript'>
     function info(theElement, id)
     {
         tr_id = 'cat_' + id;
         alert(tr_id + ' ' + document.getElementById(tr_id).class);
     }
 </script>
```

Working example: 
http://jsfiddle.net/rQpeu/

What am I missing?

**Update**

I was using the wrong descriptor - should use Classname.  Thanks for the prompt responses everyone!  Updated jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/rQpeu/3/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

element.class is incorrect.

You need to use element.**className**.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className

Answer (score 1):

Use `className` instead of `class`  [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rQpeu/2/)

```
 <script language='javascript'>
  function info(theElement, id)
     {
         tr_id = 'cat_' + id;
         alert(tr_id + ' ' + document.getElementById(tr_id).className);
     }
 </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
document.getElementById(tr_id).className
```

or for modern browsers which support `DOMTokenList`:

```
var d = document.getElementById(tr_id).classList
// d[0] would return class_a
```

Answer (score 1):

It's classname, not class.

```
alert(tr_id + ' ' + document.getElementById(tr_id).className);
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/rQpeu/1/)**

See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/element.className

Answer (score 1):

Use `className` instead of `class`

```
document.getElementById(tr_id).className
```